# CouchDB: map-reduce in Erlang

Tags: erlang, couchdb, mapreduce

How can I write map-reduce functions in Erlang for CouchDB? I am sure Erlang is faster than JavaScript.

Comment: Can't be a coincidence: http://browsertoolkit.com/fault-tolerance.png

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do so using [erlview](http://github.com/mmcdanie/erlview/tree/master), which is within the top ten hits on Google for "couchdb erlang view" and is listed on the CouchDB [wiki page for other-language view servers](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_server).

Comment: With the next release of CouchDB erlang views will be built in. You won't even have to download and setup erlview to make it work.

Comment: CouchDB 0.10 (released October 2009) and later support Erlang views natively. A good writeup is at http://blog.echolibre.com/2010/02/couchdb-custom-erlang-map-functions/

Answer (score 25):

```
pmap(F, L) ->
    Parent = self(),
    Pids = [spawn(fun() ->
                     Parent ! {self(), F(X)}
                  end) || X -> L],
    [receive {Pid, Res} -> Res end || Pid < - Pids].
```

I believe I did, Bob.

Comment: Needs the cartoon pasted in there for added value :D

Comment: Lulz...consider my afternoon laugh provided for.